# simple way to detect that [console] app is running under MSVC

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++

This is for debugging purposes, my C++ console app needs to behave a little differently when it runs under MSVC (2008) vs when it is run notunder MSVC.

Is there simple way to detect that it runs under msvc ?

Thanks

Comment: An application that changes its behavior when debugged is ... eh... really hard to debug. Is this a good idea?

Comment: @Bo: [That might be the intent.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugging#Anti-debugging)

Comment: Right, YMMV. I have some terrible experiences with in-house applications that work when tested, but break in production. :-(

Comment: Andrei, I've managed this in the past with a special cmd line flag that VS passes to the exe on execution.  You can set them in Project->Properties->Configuration Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345%28VS.85%29.aspx) function returns true when running under the debugger. [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679303%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) a list of all available debugger related functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can find out easily if it's being debugged using IsDebuggerPresent api.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(v=vs.85).aspx

Then you could do a findwindow to see if the visual studio window is present...

Or as ben said you could enumerate the processes using tlhelp32.h functions Process32First and Process32Next get the parent process of your application (PID) then use GetModuleFileNameEx to
check process name equals to visual studio executable file...

Comment: Instead of playing games with `FindWindow`, which could give false positives, why not check the parent process?

Comment: The parent process won't be MSVC if the debuggee is started first, and MSVC then attached. I can't tell from the question if that's an issue.

Comment: @MSalters i doubt that will happen...but it's possible anyway i don't know what exactly Andrei wants to implement maybe he wants to check if his app is runned by him or by a user ;)